# my PDE solution not matching with text book solutio

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A small question from text book; my solution does not match with text book solution. Please help.

$$4 \frac {\partial u} {\partial x} + \frac {\partial u} {\partial y} = 3u$$

given $u(0,y) = \Bbb e ^{-y} - \Bbb e ^{-5y}$.

My solution: let $u(x,y) = X(x) Y(y)$ so, after rewriting $4X'Y+XY'=3XY$;
diving by $XY$ and re-arranging: $4 \frac {X'} X = 3 - \frac {Y'} Y = a$, thus $X=c_1 \Bbb e ^{a \frac x 4}$ and $Y = c_2 \Bbb e ^{(3-a)y}$. Then the general solution is

$$u=c \; \Bbb e ^{a \frac x 4  +(3-a)y}$$

where $a,c$ are constants.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Your solution does not coincide with the initial condition at x=0.

Comment: @Did yeah .. so wondering what is the actual solution ..? two terms in the general solution .. I am not getting ..

Comment: Show how you reached your solution - otherwise I am afraid this is a no-context question.

Comment: I have added what I have tried ..sry ..this was my first Q and not conversant with formatting math equations ..

Comment: If the question is "am i wrong?" the answer is yes you are wrong since your u(0,y) is not what it should be. If the question is *where* you are wrong, then you might want to explain what your X and Y are (presumably, u(x,y)=XY but apart from that...) and how you pass from 4X'Y+XY'=3XY to 4X'/X=3-Y'/Y=a instead of 4X'/X=3-Y'/Y.

Comment: hi ...  that is how PDE are solved by separation of variables right ..:(

Comment: @tarzan: No, not all PDEs are solved by the method of separation of variables; yours is one such equation.

Answer (score 0):

Your computations are correct; the fact that you do not get the correct solution means that your initial assumption was wrong: the equation *cannot* be solved by separating the variables. Let us try another method.

Make the change of variables $X=x, Y=4y-x$ and let $U(X,Y) = u(x,y)$. Then $\frac {\partial u} {\partial x} = \frac {\partial U} {\partial X} - \frac {\partial U} {\partial Y}$ and $\frac {\partial u} {\partial y} = 4 \frac {\partial U} {\partial Y}$. Substituting these into the original equation you get a new one: $4 \frac {\partial U} {\partial X} = 3U$, so $U(X,Y) = \Bbb e ^{\frac 3 4 X} C(Y)$, with $C$ an unknown function. Reverting to the original variables, $u(x,y) = \Bbb e ^{\frac 3 4 x} C(4y-x)$. Imposing the initial condition gives $u(0,y) = C(4y) = \Bbb e ^{-y} - \Bbb e ^{-5y}$; replacing $y$ by $y - \frac x 4$ you get $C(4y-x) = \Bbb e ^{-y +\frac x 4} - \Bbb e ^{-5 y + \frac 5 4 x}$. Plugging this back in the formula of $u$ gives the solution: $u(x,y) = \Bbb e ^{\frac 3 4 x} \Big( \Bbb e ^{-y +\frac x 4} - \Bbb e ^{-5 y + \frac 5 4 x} \Big)$.

Comment: imagine if the initial condition of the problem was not given was not given ... then is it still my solution wrong  ...? if the solutions of the chapter were not given .. I would not have know where I was heading

Comment: @tarzan: Indeed, without the initial condition your solution would have been good. This shows that, without initial conditions, a PDE may have very many (possibly infinitely many) solutions. In fact, even with initial conditions, there are PDEs that do not have a unique solution.

Comment: how did you format all my math equations ..?

Comment: @tarzan: Essentially, it is LaTeX code. We have a brief tutorial for beginners [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).